# Unable to reproduce Keccak256 "hello world" hash within EVM

Tags: evm, lll

My toy program contains the following lines:

```
(seq
  (def 'hash 0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad)
  (def 'result 0x0aef6cc8d178ff0f7950a7d02a6f9061ede19bc359fb1f777e7f20a5c729bf77)
  (lit 0 "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32")
  (mstore 28 hash)
  (if (eq (sha3 0 60) result) (stop) (invalid)))
```

`hash` is output from `web3.sha3("hello world")`

`result` is output from `web3.sha3(web3.toHex("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32")+"47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad")`

Why does this program evaluate to invalid? If I remove the signed message prefix  and just compare hashes of `hello world` then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues here.

(1) LLL doesn't understand the string syntax. It interprets "\x19" as a literal 4 bytes rather than the single byte 0x19.  Same for "\n" which is intended to be 0x0a. I don't know a good way around this other than writing the bytes directly using `mstore8`.

(2) You need the `{encoding: 'hex'}` option to `web3.sha3` when calculating `result`.

```
> web3.sha3(web3.toHex("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32")+"47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad", {encoding: 'hex'})
"0x93100cc9477ba6522a2d7d5e83d0e075b167224ed8aa0c5860cfd47fa9f22797"
```

The following is clunky but it seems to work.

```
(seq
  (def 'hash 0x47173285a8d7341e5e972fc677286384f802f8ef42a5ec5f03bbfa254cb01fad)
  (def 'result 0x93100cc9477ba6522a2d7d5e83d0e075b167224ed8aa0c5860cfd47fa9f22797)
  (mstore8 0 0x19)  ; the "\0x19"
  (lit 1 "Ethereum Signed Message:")
  (mstore8 25 0x0a) ; the "\n"
  (lit 26 "32")
  (mstore 28 hash)
  (if (eq (sha3 0 60) result) (stop) (invalid)))
```